# Como retirar uma palavra de uma string e todas as outras subsequentes?

Tags: javascript, regex

Tenho uma `string` `url` e preciso retirar a palavra **Dashboard** dela e todas os outros caracteres subsequentes(incluindo barras).

Exemplo:

```
"Algumcoisa/Dashboard/Outracoisa/Maisalgumacoisa"
```

Quero que fique assim:

```
"Algumacoisa/"
```

Já tentei:

```
pathname = window.location.pathname
url = pathname.replace("/Dashabord.*/",'')
```

Sempre consigo testar esse código em sites de `regex` como o `https://www.regextester.com/99144`, mas nunca consigo realizar o `replace`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) (*eu particularmente não gosto*) funciona com essa modificação essencial que é retirar as aspas duplas que envolve o seu teste, porque ai ele testa um texto do jeito que está escrito e não realmente a palavra que deseja buscar e eliminar a partir dela toda o resto, ***exemplo***:

```js
pathname = "Algumcoisa/Dashboard/Outracoisa/Maisalgumacoisa"
url = pathname.replace(/Dashboard.*/,'');
console.log(url);
```

Para mim é melhor utilizar um forma mais legível de código, primeiro busque com [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) a posição que começa a pesquisa *Dashboard* e depois com [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) retorna parte daquele texto, ***exemplo***:

```js
const url = "Algumcoisa/Dashboard/Outracoisa/Maisalgumacoisa";
const index = url.indexOf("Dashboard");
const newUrl = url.substring(0, index);
console.log(newUrl);
```

<sup>***Referencias:***</sup>

- [Javascript - regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

  *Expressões regulares são padrões utilizados para selecionar combinações de caracteres em uma string. Em JavaScript, expressões regulares também são objetos. Elas podem ser utilizadas com os métodos [exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) e [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) do objeto [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), e com os métodos [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), [search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search), e [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) do objeto [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).*
- [Javascript - indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

  *O método indexOf() retorna o primeiro índice em que o elemento pode ser encontrado no array, retorna -1 caso o mesmo não esteja presente.*
- [Javascript - substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

  *O método substring() retorna um subconjunto de uma string entre um indice e outro, ou até o final da string.*

Comment: Você poderia explicar o que o código faz?

Comment: Calma @CodigodeSenior eu já sei como funciona o site e acabei de explicar !

Comment: @novic você sabe explicar porque a minha abordagem não é executada pelo javascript?

Comment: @hellysonMacedo trabalhar com `regex` eu não gosto, eu não recomendo, só no último caso, porque, se existe metodos prontos que possam resolver o seu problema, utilize é mais tranquilo no seu desenvolvimento e fica até mais claro para posteriores mudanças. Porque o seu não funcionou tenho que fazer um teste mas, deve estar errado o teste por isso não obteve o resultado esperado.

Comment: Bom eu descobri e vou disponibilizar também como solução! @hellysonMacedo

Comment: @novic muito obrigado mesmo pela sua nova solução e ainda mais pela correção que vocês fez na minha, quebrei muito a cabeça aqui pensando que o erro era na regex e nunca passou pela minha cabeça que fosse as aspas.

Comment: Regex é assim @hellysonMacedo eu particularmente odeio resolver, mas, em alguns momentos é inevitável ..